# Can't get access to Angular constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get access to my angular `.constant` via this code:

```
angular
    .module('coreApp')
    .constant('MY_CONSTANTS', {
        myConstant_1: 'My constant'
    })
```

My controller:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$log', '$rootScope', '$location', MY_CONSTANTS, MyController]);

function MyController($log, $rootScope, $location, MY_CONSTANTS, MyController) {
    $log.debug(myConstant_1);
}
```

But i can't get the value and output the value from my constants. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap dependency inside `single quote`/`double quote` while specifying it inside an array. Here you are missing quotes aroud `MY_CONSTANTS`.

And then at the end of DI Array, it should be your controller function `ArticleController` not `MyController`

```
.controller('MyController', 
   ['$log', '$rootScope', '$location', 'MY_CONSTANTS', ArticleController]);
                                      //^^^^^ change here..
function ArticleController($log, $rootScope, $location, MY_CONSTANTS) {
    $log.debug(MY_CONSTANTS.myConstant_1);
}
```

Comment: I added quote, but still can't get the value

Comment: The main issue is how i tried to get the value. Thank you for your answer where you fixed all my issues, now it works!

Comment: @Ludmila Yeah. Its all there in code, Glad to help you, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MY_CONSTANTS.myConstant_1` instead of just `myConstant_1`. And your code will be `$log.debug(MY_CONSTANTS.myConstant_1);`
And you also didn't wrap your `MY_CONSTANTS` into quote.